# Feeding URL values for start_requests for scraping from another spider

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm completely a newbie for both python and scrapy. I'm trying to create a scraper where it will first scrape the URL, get all the URLs to be scraped and fetch the URL values one by one to the another scraper and then fetch the actual needed data.

As of now, I have two separate spiders fetches the values and save it to a text file. Then second spider crawls the URLs from the text file.

But is there any way to have the first spider to call the second spider and feed the URLs one after the other instead of storing it in an external file and triggering it manually after the URL fetching is over?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use two spiders in order to do that. You could do that using only one spider with multiple callbacks. I can help you find a solution if you share how you collect your URLs and what kind of operation you do with your second spider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You describe the exact behaviour of a Scrapy [CrawlSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider), where you specify rules for url extraction and a method for content parsing. Look at some examples like [this one](https://realpython.com/web-scraping-and-crawling-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/) to learn the basics, it should help.

Comment: Thanks, it helped to move in the right direction. Cheers!